# Service for hosting native JavaScript ES modules

Tags: http, cdn, cors

We will be serving static javascript ES modules and looking for an all-in-one hosting platform that is easy to use.

- It must provide CORS headers (ES modules enable CORS by default)
- HTTP/2 support is mandatory
- Ability to set very long caching headers (content never changes)
- Mirrored all across the world for fast transfers with low latency.
- Pushing a new version should be a simple oneliner.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [CDNjs.com](https://cdnjs.com/):

- It supports CORS headers, it is dedicated to JavaScript after all.
- It supports HTTP/2 as well as SPDY.
- The cache duration is 355 days, which is probably plenty long enough.
- Cloudflare is used as the CDN, they provide it to cdnjs.org for free.

Adding your library is a bit more than a one-liner unfortunately as you need to submit a pull request to their GitHub repository.  You will also need to have a certain popularity requirement:

> For the new library request issue, please make sure it's not a personal project, we have a basic requirement for the popularity, like 200 stars on GitHub or 800 downloads/month on npm registry.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This would be great for a popular library. Most of our packages are really only interesting within the organization, so it, unfortunately, doesn't fit my use case.